# OrientDB graph: How to use Java API to create a new Record?

Tags: java, record, orientdb

I know how to create an Record with the Web GUI of OrientDB. **How am I able to create a New Record with the Java API?**
This is what I have done with the GUI so far.

You can download the full version of the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR4r6.jpg)

[image]

This is my code so far but my knowledge is to low. I just know how to handle Vertex.

```
    OrientGraphFactory ogf = new OrientGraphFactory(
            "plocal:/home/paulkalkbrenner/Dokumente/odb/databases/ConnectER", "admin", "admin");
    OrientGraph og = ogf.getTx();

    try {
        System.out.println("message bevor vertex");

        Vertex relation0_vertex = og.addVertex(null);
        relation0_vertex.setProperty("Lastname", rel0);

        //System.out.println("Features = " + og.getFeatures());
        for (Vertex v : og.getVertices()) {
            System.out.println(v.getProperty("Lastname"));
        }
    }
    finally {
        og.shutdown();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
OrientGraphFactory ogf = new OrientGraphFactory(
        "plocal:/home/paulkalkbrenner/Dokumente/odb/databases/ConnectER", "admin", "admin");
    OrientGraph og = ogf.getTx();

    OClass cl=og.createVertexType("Person", "V");
    cl.createProperty("LastName", OType.STRING);

    OrientVertex v1=og.addVertex("class:Person");
    v1.setProperties("Lastname","Alessandro");

    for (Vertex v : og.getVertices()) {
        System.out.println(v.getProperty("Lastname"));
    }

    og.shutdown();
```

Comment: you mean the setProperties creates a new Record?

Comment: with OrientVertex v1=og.addVertex("class:Person") the new vertex of type Person is created
and with v1.setProperties("Lastname","Alessandro") is set the property Lastname

Comment: so you mean when I create a new Record with the GUI and put in Alessandro, it is the same as setProperties("Lastname","Alessandro") ?

Comment: when you create a new Record with the GUI and put in Alessandro ,it is the same as og.addVertex("class:Person").setProperties("Lastname","Alessandro");